# How Import/sync Social media contacts (Facebook, Linkedin, Google) in Android APP?

Tags: android, social-media

I wants to import social media contacts (Facebook, Linkedin, Google) in to my android app, I searched a lot but yet not reached to the proper solution. So any help will really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This tutorial will help you out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815900/Android-social-network-integration You need to use sdk for all those sites and then as per your need you can access the data you need

Comment: you have to add permission ...